# Enable snmp read-only on Cumulus HW

Tags: snmp

What is the right way to add SNMP READ-only on a Cumulus switch and restrict access by multiple source IP addresses blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way (as of Cumulus release 4.1) to restrict SNMP by multiple source-address blocks is:

```
net add snmp-server listening-address all
net add snmp-server readonly-community public access 10.1.1.0/24
net add snmp-server readonly-community public access 192.168.1.0/24
net commit
```

Reference: [Cumulus SNMP reference](https://docs.cumulusnetworks.com/cumulus-linux-41/Monitoring-and-Troubleshooting/Simple-Network-Management-Protocol-SNMP/)